# Rank of Laplacian operator on space of degree $n$ 2-variable homogeneous polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n \geq 2$, and let $V_n = \left\{a_{0}x^n+a_{1}x^{n-1}y+a_{2}x^{n-2}y^2+\dotsb+a_{n}y^n: a_0,a_1,\dotsc,a_n \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ be the vector space of real degree $n$ homogeneous polynomials in 2 variables. Let $B_n$ be the ordered basis $x_n, x^{n-1}y, x^{n-2}y^2, \dotsc, y_n$ for $V_n$. Define the Laplacian operator, $L \colon V_n \to V_{n-2}$, by $$L(f) = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}$$ and note that $L$ is linear. Let $A$ be the matrix of $L$ with respect to the ordered bases $B_n$ and $B_{n-2}$. What is the rank of $A$ (or equivalently, the rank of $L$)?

I was able to describe the columns of matrix $A$ by considering what $L$ does to the elements of $B_n$, and I found by trying some examples that the rank of $A$ appears to be $n-1$. But I can't see how to prove this. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that this is an operator from an $(n+1)$-dimensional space to a $(n-1)$-dimensional space. Try and write out an explicit form of the general $(n-1) \times (n+1)$ matrix with respect to the canonical bases. From there, it should be quite straightforward to prove the claim for the rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By direct computation with $f=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^{n-k}y^k$ we have $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}a_{k}(k+2)(k+1)x^{n-2-k}y^k$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}a_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)x^{n-2-k}y^{k}$. Adding and collecting terms we see that $L= \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(a_k+a_{k+2})(k+2)(k+1)x^{n-2-k}y^k$.

It's not hard to see that the matrix has $n+1$ columns and $n-1$ rows with each row having $(k+1)(k+2)$ in the $k$-th and $k+2$-th columns and zeroes everywhere else. Since this matrix is in row-echelon form and all of the entries on the main diagonal are non-zero we conclude that the rank is $n-1$.

Comment: @TravisWillse you're correct I dropped a dimension. Thanks.